# Featured Images on Front Page

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, page-template

I currently have a static front page and a /blog.

My goal is to have the front page be a grid of hand selected images (similar to a portfolio). I would like to be able to easily switch the images are featured on this page without having to change the raw html.

Is the best way to do this, using custom fields on a page? Or is there a better way to handle managing featured images on a static page?

Thanks!

Comment: I would just create a loop with a "featured" category, and then just display the featured image of each post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two categories should do the trick.

1. Featured posts - This category should be applied to posts that you want to show on your home page, with that images grid. You can limit the number of posts (so only the, for example, 6 newest ones would appear) and select the featured image for them on each post's properties. You can [limit number of posts](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/limit-number-of-posts-on-home-page-to-one-the-latest) easily, and you can also [exclude other categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Exclude_Categories_From_Your_Home_Page) from your home page.
2. Blog posts - a general category with a name such as 'blog' would include every other post you've got on your website. This category would have a visible link on your home page, and would be accesible through www.yousite.com/blog/

I think this would be my way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to use the front-page.php template and put a custom loop on it and then style the loop how you'd like it to show the content.

Comment: How would I be able to manage the content of the loop though? Custom fields on the page? Or feature category as Mario says above?