# For homepage images (for small business website), is it better to use custom fields or post_thumbnail?

Tags: custom-field, images, post-thumbnails, homepage, customization

Already searched on here and couldn't find question so forgive me if it's been asked. *I'm trying to use dynamic images on a homepage so my client can maintain the images.* I've seen tutorials where one person uses post_thumbnails while another uses custom fields.  Do I need to create a post for each image and display post_thumbnail on homepage? Or is it better to use custom fields for one post to display multiple images?

Reference:

`the_post_thumbnail()` 
http://ontwik.com/wordpress/creating-a-wordpress-theme-part-1/

`get_post_custom()`
http://ontwik.com/web-design/how-to-design-a-portfolio-site-part-2/

[similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/featured-images-on-front-page)

Comment: Are you setting a static page as the homepage?

Comment: Yes, I made a custom home.php for homepage. Homepage shows different products they carry.

Comment: If `Products` are custom posts, then post thumbnails will be a better option, but it means only one image per post. If your client is adding/editing the products via the visual editor, then he can upload the images in the media library and use the image urls wherever he wants the images.

Comment: You're welcome... no problem, I'm glad I could help a bit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your page is a portfolio index, where each image is meant to relate to a post or page, then post thumbnails would be the way to go.

If your page is simply a gallery page, and the images don't relate to any content beyond that page, then the best method would be to upload images as [attachments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Image_and_File_Attachments) to that page and output them in your template with [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_attachments_for_the_current_post).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Let me do some research and talking to client.

Answer (score 0):

better is the_post_thumbnail();

custom fields were used while thumbnail feature was not introduced.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Let me do some research and talking to client.